# Different tints (opacities) of a spot colour as separate discrete swatches in the swatch panel?

Tags: swatches, spot-color

In Indesign is there a way to setup various tints or opacities of the same Pantone Spot colour as separate discrete swatches? It would be helpful for me as I would like to set up a Data Merge function that would actively search out different tonalities of said spot colour swatch in an automated way.

Comment: What software are you using? I supposed InDesign in my answer becasue that's my app of choice. ^^'

Answer (score 1):

Select the PMS color that you would like to save a tint of.

Open your **Color Palette** and set the percent of the swatch to the percent that you would like to save.

Click on on the stacked lines in the upper right of the **Color Palette** and select **Add to Swatches**.

[image: Add to Swatches]

The tint will now show up in your **Swatches Palette** like this:

[image: Swatch Palette]

You can repeat this for as many tints as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these are called 'Tint Swatches'. Select your Pantone Swatch, set its tint to a non-100 percentage, then open the Swatches palette's options. You should be able to choose the 'New Tint Swatch' option there.